# Proper way to micro Warp Prism and Sentries?

Tags: starcraft-2

Lately I really like to load a Warp Prism with 2 Sentries and 2 Zealots in PvZ.
I fly into the Zergs main when his army is not there and unload my units, force-fielding the ramp and doing **terrible terrible damage**. I also want to warp in some more Zealots asap.

I wonder how to micro this properly:

- Unload units
- turn the prism into warp-in mode
- select sentry and cast force field

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can actually unload units while the prism is in phasing mode.

The most efficent way to accomplish what you want to have done is to have your sentries on a hotkey before you go in for your attack.

- Fly in
- Set the prism into phasing mode.
- Shift unload. (Everything to this point can be shift queued so that you have a few extra actions to do something else).
- Warp in a set of units as it is unloading.
- Select your sentry and force field the ramp.

This will get you the maximum number of warp cycles possible when doing your drop because your warp prism will be in phase mode as soon as possible.

Comment: It's weird that it still makes you select a location to unload though.

Answer (score 1):

Yea, I think that is proper way to do it. As optimization you can queue shift+unload command and then shift+warp-mode. So you can immediately select sentry after unload, cast force field and that warp zealots.